# Subsequence convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hello I'm wondering the following :

If we suppose $ \forall k\geq 2 : (s_{nk})_{n \geq 1}  $ is a convergent sequence then does it implies that $s_n$ is a convergent sequence ?

My guess would be no but I can't find a counterexample ...

Thanks for you help.

Comment: @danielson Well the question says **for all** $k$. I'm pretty sure $s_{3n}$ isn't a convergent sequence

Comment: I was assuming that the OP meant $s_{n_k}$, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence $$s_n=\begin{cases} 0 & \mbox{if}\:\: n \:\:\mbox{composite,}\\ 1 & \mbox{if}\:\: n  \:\:\mbox{prime.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: So  every subsequence  $ s_{nk} = 0 $ so indeed it converges to 0 but the subsequence with primes { s2, s3, s5, ... , } is equal to  1 so we have two different subsequence limit thus $ s_n $ doesn't converges. Thanks ! very nice